# Want my drop down menu to go in front of the other elements on my page when I hover over it

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I have a drop down menu working perfectly, styled right and all. But only problem is, when i hover over it, the drop down menu goes behind other elements on my page eg. my title.

My drop down menu is above the title.

Can anyone help me get it to drop down over my title.

I cant edit my html, I must style it in css with what I already have in the html (no new id tags etc.)

Heres a bit of my html:

```
<body>

<ul id = "dropdown">
<li>Twitter</li>
<li>Facebook</li>
<li>Google+</li>
<li>Linkedin</li>
<li>Share</li>
</ul>

<div id = "title"><img src = "round_arrow_right.png">Gallery One</div>
```

This is the css:

```
#dropdown {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 100px;
}

#title {width: 80%; 
margin: 0 auto;
margin-top: 90px;
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#997600,#e5bd6e); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
background: -o-linear-gradient(#997600,#e5bd6e); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(#997600,#e5bd6e); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
background: linear-gradient(#997600, #e5bd6e); /* Standard syntax (must be last) */
height: 100px;
border-radius: 30px;
-webkit-transform:rotate(-4deg);
margin-bottom: 70px;
text-align: center;
font-size: 60px; 
box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #000000;
font-family: arial;
padding-top: 20px;}

#dropdown :nth-child(1) {
background-color: gray;
color: white;
border: 6px solid white;
}

#dropdown :nth-child(2) {
border: 6px solid white;
}

#dropdown :nth-child(3) {
background-color: gray;
color: white;
border: 6px solid white;
}

#dropdown :nth-child(4) {
border: 6px solid white;
}

#dropdown :nth-child(5) {border: 6px solid white;
border-top: 1px solid black;
border-bottom-right-radius: 7px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 7px;
font-weight: bold;
}


#dropdown li {
display: none;
}
#dropdown li:last-child {
display: block;
}
#dropdown:hover li {
display: block;
}

ul#dropdown {
margin-top: -4px;
}
```

You probably dont need all this code to answer my questions, but said id insert it for a more precise answer,

Thanks a Million

Answer (score 3):

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H5gpb/)

Give `#dropdown` a `z-index` of `999px`.

```
#dropdown {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 100px;
  z-index:999;
}
```

It doesn't *have* to be `999`, but anything over `1` would work perfectly. `999` just makes sure it's on front for 99% of the time.

Comment: @user3594463 you may want to tick accepted answer for this. Worked for  me too.